# How to clear setTimeout inside Javascript Object?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, cleartimeout

I have an object that I have a few functions inside that I am using setTimout inside. I'm trying to clear the timeout using clearTimeout.. but I'm not hitting it right.

```
var ExpireSession = {
    killSession: function () {
        var TESTVAR2 = setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.href = "error/expired.aspx";
        }, 15000);
    },

    stopTimers: function (){
        clearTimeout(ExpireSession.killSession.TESTVAR2)
    }
}
```

Before 15 seconds I am triggering: ExpireSession.stopTimers(); but it does not stop it. Any ideaas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You've to define the timer as a property of `ExpireSession`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because JavaScript has functional scope, `TESTVAR2` will only be defined within `killSession`. To reference it, you can set it as a property of ExpireSession:

```
killSession: function () {
  this._TESTVAR2 = setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.href = "error/expired.aspx";
  }, 15000);
},
stopTimers: function () {
  clearTimout(this._TESTVAR2);
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. Can you explain why adding "this" to the variable made it accessible? I'm not following. Thank you!

Comment: When using a `var` declaration, you are defining a local variable. In JavaScript, these are local to the scope (in this case a function) where they were defined. When you are using `this` here, you are actually adding a property to `ExpireSession`. That is, `ExpireSession._TESTVAR2` is your timeout. Because `killSession` and `stopTimers` are properties of `ExpireSession`, they can both access the `_TESTVAR2` property.

Answer (score 2):

`var TESTVAR2` is a variable that is local to the function it is declared within. It is not a property of an object.

If you want to access it as a property of an object, then you must define it as such:

```
ExpireSession.killSession.TESTVAR2 = setTimeout(function () {
```

(You might be able to make use of `this` depending on how you call the function).